# Question on an equality in deriving covariance matrix of a gaussian state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I am reading [Quantum continuous variables](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=bMItDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT53&lpg=PT53&dq=made%20of%20group%20representations%20able%20to%20bring%20unitary%20operators%20outside%20the%20evaluation&source=bl&ots=hkFP2LC5_o&sig=ACfU3U3cx3hiWNVjvMyCqw7Bdb8J8qb4VQ&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMosTTofLjAhUPHXAKHSt4DEIQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=made%20of%20group%20representations%20able%20to%20bring%20unitary%20operators%20outside%20the%20evaluation&f=false) by A.Serafini.
(Equations are not rendered in this link. Please look at the second link)

I have a question on the *last equality* of the equation [(3.49)](https://postimg.cc/LYPQR0s4) which the author comments; "Thanks to the use we made of group representations, ... bring the unitary operators outside of the expectation..." as you can check in the link.

> Here is the equality I want to prove in [(3.49)](https://postimg.cc/LYPQR0s4):
>   $$
> \text{Tr} \bigg[ \bigotimes_{j=1}^n \sum_{m=0}^\infty e^{-\xi_j m} |m\rangle_{j} 
> \ {}_{j} \langle m| \ \ \{ S \hat{\textbf{r}}, \hat{\textbf{r}}^T S^T \} \bigg]=S\ \text{Tr} \bigg[ \bigotimes_{j=1}^n \sum_{m=0}^\infty e^{-\xi_j m} |m\rangle_{j} 
> \ {}_{j}  \langle m| \ \ \{ \hat{\textbf{r}}, \hat{\textbf{r}}^T \} \bigg] S^T
> $$
>   where $S$ is a symplectic $2n \times 2n$ real matrix and other relevant definitions are given below.

I don't see how the author's comments lead to $S$ and its transpose $S^T$ coming out of the trace.

---

**Relevant definitions**

For simplicity, I will assume $n=1$ from now on. Then $ \hat{\textbf{r}} = \begin{pmatrix} \hat x \\ \hat p \end{pmatrix} $ and $ \hat{\textbf{r}}^T = \big ( \hat x  ,\hat p \big )  $ where the hat represents operators in Hilbert space and superscript $T$ is the transpose. Also, by definition, for any suitable $\hat {\textbf{a}}$ $$\{\ \hat{\textbf{a}},\hat{\textbf{a}}^T\} := \hat{\textbf{a}} \hat{\textbf{a}}^T +(\hat{\textbf{a}} \hat{\textbf{a}}^T)^T$$ so that $$\{\ \hat{\textbf{r}},\hat{\textbf{r}} ^T\} = \hat{\textbf{r}} \hat{\textbf{r}}^T +(\hat{\textbf{r}} \hat{\textbf{r}}^T)^T= \begin{pmatrix} \hat x \\ \hat p \end{pmatrix} \big ( \hat x  ,\hat p \big) +\bigg( \begin{pmatrix} \hat x \\ \hat p \end{pmatrix} \big ( \hat x  ,\hat p \big)  \bigg)^T = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2\hat x^2 & \hat x \hat p +\hat p \hat x \\
\hat p \hat x + \hat x \hat p & 2\hat p^2
\end{pmatrix}$$ .

$S\in M_{2 \times 2} (\mathbb R)$ is just a real-symplectic matrix which by definition satisfies $S \Omega S^T = \Omega$ where $\Omega := \begin{pmatrix} 0 \ 1 \\-1 \ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Note $S \hat{\textbf{r}}$ is a two- by- one column vector with linear combination of operators $\hat x$ and $\hat p$ as its elements.

Finally, 
$\sum_{m=0}^\infty e^{-\xi m} |m\rangle \langle m|$ with $\xi >0 $ is just the density operator $\rho$ expressed in the Fock basis.

I am sure that trace of a matrix having operators as elements is defined to be done element-wise. Hence, in the case $n=1$, the trace above results in a two-by-two matrix having operators as elements.

---

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mind giving some details here such as to make this self-contained? This would help answering the question, and make it of value to future readers

Comment: @Norbert Schuch I added relevant definitions and some thoughts.

Comment: One still has to go and check (3.49).  Can you distill the essence of the equation and put it in the question?  It is more likely that someone who answers knows the basics of Gaussian states and does not want to look up that equation than the other way round.

Comment: There's no trace in the equations that you gave, so it's not clear what the question is.

Comment: @Brick "Tr" in the equation means trace

Comment: Right. But I don't see which equation you have provided that includes a trace.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch  I edited to include the equality.

Comment: @Brick I edited to include the equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the answer. Writing down a problem always helps.

The very definition of trace of a matrix having operators as elements implies that the trace can "commute" with matrices having numbers as elements. More precisely, for a matrix $\hat{\textbf{M}}$ with operatorial elements and a real matrix $S$, since trace acts only on operators,

$$ \text{ij}^{th}\ \text{element of }\ \ \text{Tr} \bigg[S \hat{\textbf{M}} S^T \bigg] :=  \text{Tr} \bigg[\sum_{l,m}S_{il}  \hat{{M}}_{lm} S^T_{mj} \bigg]=  \sum_{l,m}S_{il} \text{Tr} \big[ \hat M_{lm}  \big]S^T_{mj} = \text{ij}^{th}\ \text{element of } \ \  S  \text{Tr} \big[\hat{\textbf{M}} \big]  S^T  $$ proving $$ \text{Tr} \bigg[S \hat{\textbf{M}} S^T \bigg] =S  \text{Tr} \big[\hat{\textbf{M}} \big]  S^T    \ \ -(1)$$.

Now the original equation becomes, $\hat \rho$ being the density operator,  $$\text{Tr}\big[ \hat \rho \{ S \hat{\textbf{r}}, \hat{\textbf{r}}^T S^T \} \big]= \text{Tr}\big[ \hat \rho S\{  \hat{\textbf{r}}, \hat{\textbf{r}}^T  \}S^T \big]= \text{Tr}\big[  S  \hat \rho\{  \hat{\textbf{r}}, \hat{\textbf{r}}^T  \}S^T \big]= S \text{Tr}\big[   \hat \rho\{  \hat{\textbf{r}}, \hat{\textbf{r}}^T  \}\big]S^T $$
where we have used (1) in the last equality. Note $\hat \rho \{  \hat{\textbf{r}}, \hat{\textbf{r}}^T  \}$ is defined as $\hat \rho$ multiplying element-wise to the matrix $\{  \hat{\textbf{r}}, \hat{\textbf{r}}^T  \}$ having operators as elements. Note the use of boldface to denote a finite dimensional vector(or matrix) having operator elements, not numbers.